# Disabled textarea without color change

Tags: html, textarea

How do I make a textarea that is disabled, but the background and text colors don't change? Is it possible?

Comment: What kind of text area are you talking about?  HTML? Java?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using a styled textarea you could easily add a class to it that has the same styling as the other (not disabled) elements.

Take a look at this:

```
<style>
input[type=button] {
    background: #FFF;
    border:1px solid #000;
    color: #000;
    padding: 10px;
}
</style>

<input type="button" disabled="disabled" value="I'm disabled :(" />
<input type="button"  value="I'm not :)" />
```

That's an example of how you can change the appearance of disabled elements (buttons in this case, but textareas should work the same).

It looks something like this:

[image: Preview]

Comment: I mean that if you're using styled input elements, like a specific border color or some background, you could add the same kind of styling to your disabled textarea. It should look just like your other inputs.

Comment: But that only works if you're working with css-styled textareas and inputs :)

Comment: It should work for default textareas also. I think it's only Internet Explorer that grays the background.  Just use CSS to make the text black, and the background white.

Comment: change the css class to textarea:disabled, and then it will work on a html text area